# How to correctly modify entities in EF

Tags: .net, entity-framework-6

The hierarchy is something like this:
Object A has a collection of objects B, object B has a collection of object C. Object C are already in DB and by any mean, they have to be added or modified.

Im trying to add a new object B to and an existing object A.

1) i get object A from DB, so the context track em.

```
a = db.as.Find(1);
```

2) i add object B to A (for what i understand this simply mark object B with state added)

```
a.bs.Add(b);
```

3) When object B was created, it was populated with several objects C that are not tracked by context but are in DB, so i mark them as attached or unchanged

```
foreach(var asd in b.cs)
{
  db.entry(asd).State = ...Unchanged;
}
```

4) then i save changes

all this WAS working, dont know what happend... but when this code is executed for the first time it works.

For the second time it creates an aditional object A, with an additional object B but no duplicate objects C (at least a good news).

Any idea of whats going on here? i tried a lot of changes, but every time behavior is same.

Fakhar Ahmad Rasul: The relationship its set like this

```
A: 1) id generated by db
   2) public ICollection<B> Bs;

B: 1) id generated by db
   2) public ICollection<C> Cs;
   3) public ICollection<A> As; //because of the many-to-many 

C: 1) id generated by db
   2) public ICollection<B> Bs; //because of the many-to-many
```

Eldar: all ids are generated by DB

Comment: May be you are generating the primary key of `A` entity on the class itself?

Comment: Do you have relations set up properly between the three classes?